# how to make setTimeout() work as it looks like in for-loop?

Tags: javascript

how to make setTimeout() work as it looks like in for-loop?
like this code

```
function hello() {
    for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('What\'s up!')
        }, 3000)
        console.log('Yo')
    }
}

hello()
```

it logs

```
Yo
Yo
Yo
What's up!
What's up!
What's up!
```

How can I make it logs

```
Yo
What's up(after 3 sec)
Yo
What's up(after 3 sec)
Yo
What's up(after 3 sec)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Impossible. `setTimeout` schedules the execution of the function for next cycle of the event loop, while `console.log('Yo')` is always executed immediately. You should either remove `setTimeout` or move `console.log('Yo')` inside it, or set it in a `setTimeout` itself with the same delay as the other one.

Comment: In production, We use promises to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer by clicking on that checkmark, unless there is something else about this that you want to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is this:

```js
function hello() {
    for (let index = 1; index <= 3; index++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('What\'s up!')
        }, 3000 * index)
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('Yo')
        }, 3000 * (index - 1))
    }
}
hello()
```

I basically made use of the for loop index to give each `console.log` call a different delay. Note how "Yo" is always 3000 ms ahead of "What's up".

Answer (score 2):

You need either [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion) for operations like this.

**Promise** (without [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function))

```js
async function hello(index = 0) {
    if (index >= 3) return;
    
    index += 1;

    return new Promise(function(resolve){
    
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('What\'s up!');
        resolve();
      }, 3000);
      
      console.log('Yo');
      
    }).then(hello.bind(null, index));
}

hello()
```

**Promise** (with [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function))

```js
async function hello() {
    for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        await Promise.all([
          new Promise(function(resolve){
            setTimeout(function(){
              console.log('What\'s up!');
              resolve();
            }, 3000);
          }),
          console.log('Yo')
        ]);
    }
}

hello()
```

**Recursion**

```js
function hello(index = 0) {
    if (index >= 3) return;
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('What\'s up!');
      hello(index);
    }, 3000);
    
    console.log('Yo');
    
    index++;
}

hello()
```

**PS**: Codes above assume you use ES2017 and above.

Comment: Your output is wrong, he wants to display all the "What's up!" logs after 3 seconds, not the first after 3, the second after 6 and the third after 9 seconds...

Comment: Mine is not. All the promises run in parallel, making it output everything after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() will not give you desired result even if you put 0 waiting time.
Either put both the console.log in setTimeout() or remove setTimeout().

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```js
const times = 3;
var n = 0;

function logYo(){
  console.log('Yo');
  logWhatsUp();
}

function logWhatsUp(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Whats Up');
    n++;
    if(n < times)
      logYo();
  }, 3000);
}

logYo();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a function which executes itself with setTimeout() but you would have to incorporate a global function as a counter.

```
let counter = 0;
function hello(n){
    console.log("Yo");
    console.log("What's up?);
    counter++;
    if(counter > n){
        setTimeout(hello, 3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to output every 3 seconds another pair of logs, take a look at the following snippet using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
async function hello() {
    for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        console.log('Yo');
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('What\'s up!');
                resolve();
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
}

hello();
```

Make sure you check out for example caniuse to check whether the browsers you want to support is supporting [async/await](https://caniuse.com/#search=async) and  [Promise](https://caniuse.com/#search=promise) though.

Comment: Your output is clearly different compared with the expected output mentioned in the question.